# Parsec: extending a working parser gives odd results

Tags: haskell, parsec

For a project, we are tasked to build a haskell parser / evaluator that controls a tiny arduino robot.

So to start of, I basically did some research on already implemented parser setups, and came across this one: https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language.

After (admittedly) copy-pasting the code, I started to test it. And it worked \o/.
Now it was time to extend it's functionality.

Edited code:

```
data Stmt = Seq [Stmt]
     | Assign String AExpr
     | If BExpr Stmt Stmt
     | While BExpr Stmt
     | Motor String AExpr
     | Skip
       deriving (Show)

Token.reservedNames   = [ "if"
                                , "then"
                                , "else"
                                , "while"
                                , "do"
                                , "skip"
                                , "true"
                                , "false"
                                , "not"
                                , "and"
                                , "or", "set" , "to"
                                ]
statement' :: Parser Stmt
statement' =   ifStmt
      <|> whileStmt
      <|> skipStmt
      <|> assignStmt
      <|> motorStatement

motorStatement :: Parser Stmt
motorStatement =
  do reserved "set"
     var <- identifier
     reserved "to"
     expr <- aExpression
     return $ Motor var expr
```

These are the only pieces of code I edited.
To test it all, I made a small testfile:

```
x := 4;
x := 6;
```

The above code parsed beatifully before my changes, but after I added the changes I get the following error

```
< (line 3, column 1):
< unexpected end of input
< expecting "if", "while", "skip", identifier or "set"
```

With my limited knowledge of Haskell, i'm unable to figure out why this "`unexpected end of input`" is happening.

Perhaps some Haskeller here is able to point me the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that your input parsed correctly before you made the changes. A list of statements is parsed using `sepBy1`:

```
sequenceOfStmt =
  do list <- (sepBy1 statement' semi)
     -- If there's only one statement return it without using Seq.
     return $ if length list == 1 then head list else Seq list
```

`sequenceOfStmt` is greedy in that if it sees a semi-colon it will expect to see another `statement'`. So a semi-colon should be regarded as a statement separator as opposed to a statement terminator.

Try running these tests to see how `sepBy1` behaves:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Combinator

p1 = sepBy1 (char 'a') (char ';')

test1 = parseTest p1 "a;a"      -- OK
test2 = parseTest p1 "a;a;"     -- FAILS
```

To help explore this issue, I've put the source for the ParseWhile language on lpaste.net: http://lpaste.net/163332

Comment: Reading your reply made me quickly realise my "mistake". Every semicolon makes it so that it needs / wants another line / statement. And because an empty line can't be converted into a type, it's erroring. Thank you sir!